# Landscape : Failure: landscape.lib.amp.MethodCallError: timeout

Tags: landscape

I just installed a landscape server, but I can't get the client working by using the `landscape-config` command. Here is the error :

```
landscape-config --computer-title "NAME" --account-name standalone  --url https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/message-system --ping-url http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ping

[...]
Failure: landscape.lib.amp.MethodCallError: timeout

Unknown error occurred.
```

By using telnet, I can see that connection between my client and my server on port 80 et 443 are ok.
Do you have any idea ? Does my client has to have access to the internet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so it's clear, no public internet access is needed, so that should not be your issue.

To help you further though, the full output from the command you ran is important, could you make sure you haven't missed anything when pasting?  As well, please include the the output in:

```
/var/log/landscape/broker.log
```

Beware the broker.log is repetitive, so you will want to just grab one error out, or use pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that my problem was due to a bad certificate configuration.

Comment: You should accept your own answer so the question is properly "closed". This is okay, in fact, it will earn you a special badge.